# JavaScript - How to get the real height of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to get the real height of a div `class = "group-members"` in the browser console

The block continues to load when the page scrolls to the bottom

I wrote something like this to get its height:

```js
var h = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('group-members'), null).getPropertyValue('height');
window.scroll({
    top: h,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

when I run these code it comes back

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
```

So what's wrong? How can I get the height of this variable div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a single element to window.getComputedStyle

So you should do this instead:

```js
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.group-members'))
```

Answer (score 2):

1. [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) - CSS height + padding
2. [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) - CSS height + padding + borders
3. [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) - Minimum height the element. Determine if an element is scrollable.
4. [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) - return left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, and height properties
5. [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) - returns all CSS properties of an element
6. [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) - returns defined Style of element

```js
const clientHeight = document.getElementById('group-members').clientHeight;
console.log('client Height : ', clientHeight);

const offsetHeight = document.getElementById('group-members').offsetHeight;
console.log('offset Height : ', offsetHeight);

const scrollHeight = document.getElementById('group-members').scrollHeight;
console.log('scroll Height : ', scrollHeight);

const getBoundingClientRectHeight = document.getElementById('group-members').getBoundingClientRect().height;
console.log('get Bounding Client Rect Height : ', getBoundingClientRectHeight);

const styleElementHeight = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("group-members")).height;
console.log('style Element Height : ', styleElementHeight);

const styleHeight = document.getElementById('group-members').style.height;
console.log('style Height : ', styleHeight);
```

```html
<div id="group-members" style="margin:10px;padding:20px;height:100px;">
    <h1>H1 Tag</h1>
    <p>P Tag</p>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `scrollHeight` is not equal to `clientHeight`, even in your snippet.

Comment: That definition still doesn't match. But anyway this answer doesn't address the issue at hand

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClientHeight.

```
document.getElementById("group-members")?.clientHeight
```